# Input Redirection not working

Tags: c, linux

I'm having an issue where the input redirection doesn't seem to be working for me. All the program does is that it should read a txt file, and count the frequency of every ASCII character. Although, if I do ./freq < text.txt , it doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_CHAR 255
#define PERCENTAGE100 100

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

   int c;
   double counter = 0;
   double letter[MAX_CHAR] = {0};

   while ((c = getchar()) !='\n') {
      letter[c]++;
      counter++;
}

   c=0;

   while (c < MAX_CHAR) {
   double percentage = (letter[c]/counter) * PERCENTAGE100;
   printf("For %c, frequency is %.0f, total percent is %.2f \n", c, letter[c], percentage);
   c++;
}

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I didn't check the script, before that are you sure `freq` is executable? If not do a `chmod +x` on it.

Comment: Since you aren't using `argv` or `argc`, you should use `int main(void)`. Since there are 256 possible character values, you should use `double letter[MAX_CHAR+1] = { 0.0 };` for the array.  Are you sure you want to use `double` for the counts?  It would be more usual to use `int` or `long`. However, the code shown looks like it should work as long as there is at least one newline in the file. If you have no newlines, then your loop will go infinite; you should use `while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)`. You're correct to use `int c` — that is important. Why not a `for` loop at the end?

Comment: Based on the first while it will only read the first line of the code(until it reaches a newline), check for EOF (End of File).                                      while ((c = getchar()) !=EOF)

Comment: You'll get some oddball printing effects from printing the control characters.